# What is molecular "tumbling" in NMR?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

In NMR textbooks, it is often said that small molecules tumble faster and large molecules tumble slower. What is "tumbling" exactly? When I searched for it, someone says that it is any molecular motions (translation, rotation, vibration), someone says that it is reorientation, and someone says that is is rotation.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/105614

Comment: for 'tumbling' read rotational diffusion, see Wikipedia article.  You can estimate the diffusion coefficient as a sphere with $D=k_BT/6\eta V$ where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $\eta$ the solution viscosity (in Pa s) and $V$ the volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [OP]  When I searched for it, someone says that it is any molecular motions (translation, rotation, vibration), someone says that it is reorientation, and someone says that is is rotation.

The motions relevant for NMR are those that change the strength of the magnetic field an NMR-active nucleus experiences, i.e. motions that change the chemical shielding and the location of other NMR-active nuclei. When a molecule is rotated (as a rigid body), all nuclei are affected. When there are specific vibrations (or conformational change), nuclei in a specific part of the molecule are affected. Translation only makes a difference if there is a gradient in the external magnetic field (on purpose or because of experimental challenges).

Tumbling is a stochiastic reorientation of molecules over time. To make things easier, we will think of the molecule as a rigid body and exclude conformational change from here on. Stochiastic reorientation implies that if you pick a thousand molecules in your NMR tube that happen to have the same orientation at one time, they will have very different orientations - say - a second later. So the reorientation is uncorrelated, and this is important for solution state NMR.

To give you an analogy of correlated and uncorrelated reorientation, consider a washer and dryer. During the spin cycle in the washer, clothes rotate in a correlated way (on the axis of the drum). During tumble drying, on the other hand, items of clothes change their relative orientation because of the bevels in the drum, gravity and slow drum rotation speeds. This helps separate clothes and avoids wet spots.

Why are uncorrelated reorientations important in NMR? They pop up when explaining the chemical shifts you observe, and when considering T1 and T2 relaxation (how much time do spins need to go back to their equilibrium state, and what determines peak widths).

Chemical shifts are highly orientation-specific (the orientation of the "chemical environment" or lattice with respect to the orientation of the NMR magnet). Here is an example of two carbonyl signals:

[image]

From JMR 2002, 155:15-28, copied from slide 41 in a [talk by Rienstra](https://web.mit.edu/fbml/winterschool2008/talks/Tue3%20-%20Rienstra%20-%20Chemical%20shift%20anisotropy%20and%20multidim%20recoupling.pdf)

Without tumbling, different orientations of the carbonyl show chemical shifts in a wide range (roughly 100 ppm to 250 ppm). The dotted lines are the average chemical shifts, and those are the ones you would observe for an isotropically tumbling molecule (if it tumbles faster than the timescale of individual scans in the experiment).

The influence of tumbling on relaxation phenomena is complicated but generally relies on a stochastically fluctuating magnetic field experienced by the nuclear spins. Suffice it to say that when molecules show fast tumbling rather than slow, solution-state NMR is easier to interpret and data are more useful.